# java fx editor in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2

I want to make an animation using Java FX.

Basically, I don't know where to start. I've been looking for a Java FX editor and I found out that there is an editor apart from netbeans. But that editor, now is integrated to netbeans (after netbeans 7.x.x) and I can't find the way of making a Java FX animation using the modern version of netbeans.

And, can I make an animated frame, just one? So that the rest of the frames keep the same as they were before (non-animated) ? Or do I need to start a whole new animated project and do all the coding in Java FX?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java FX is not just an animation, presentation or game building tool like Flash, but a great UI framework with the power and flexibility of Java.

It is a relatively new technology that there is no Flash like tool to do complex drawings and animations, AFAIK.

I guess you mentioned about Scene Builder as the NetBeans integrated editor in your question. Scene Builder lets you build UI through drag & drop just like the NetBeans Swing GUI Builder or Visual Studio. It uses a special XML based markup language called FXML to write the UI.

Unfortunately, It runs a lot slower than it should, even on a 3 GHz Intel Pentium 4 CPU.
IMHO, the best option is to programatically code your UI in Java FX.

**Resources**

[Official Java FX 2 Getting Started Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm)

[JavaFX 2 Scene Builder Tutorial](http://edu.makery.ch/blog/2012/11/16/javafx-tutorial-addressapp-1/)

[Another Java FX Getting Started Tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/306750-getting-started-with-javafx-2/)